# How to handle magento 1.9.1 email queue?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have upgraded to 1.9.1
everything seems to be working perfect except that the order confirmation email is being queued?
How can I change the setting so that I would like the email to be fired as soon as the order  is placed?

Answer (score 1):

You can't as far as i've saw. 1.9.1 added the queue system to make the checkout faster. To make the transactional email work you will have to set up a [cron](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-installing#install-cron).

Comment: I really don't understand how to setup cron job to make transactional emails work. Please explain. I have also installed aoe_scheduler extension. But again I am having hard time understanding how to setup a cron jobs for transactional emails

Comment: Read the documentation i added. There you will find the changes for this release also.

Comment: mbalparda is correct https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php#L188, ensure your cron is running properly. AOE_Scheduler can help facilitate this. https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

Comment: @Haya I think it is important to understand you don't specifically setup a cron for the queued email. Instead you setup one cron job for the entire store and this will automatically schedule the transactional emails.

Comment: @B00MER why 3rd party AOE_Scheduler ? Any CMS mail is common complete required feature .

Answer (score 0):

I have built and Magento extension to bypass this order email queue system and send order emails immediately without waiting for cron to run.
[Bypass Magento Email Queue](http://codecanyon.net/item/bypass-magento-email-queue/13816210)